# Defining attr_accessor in parent class using constants from child classes

Tags: ruby

I have parent class, and some child classes

```
class Base
end
```

```
class ChildNameAge < Base
  ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :age]
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
end
```

```
class ChildHeightWidth < Base
  ATTRIBUTES = [:height, :width]
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
end
```

How can I move this attr_accessor to parent class, but still use `ATTRIBUTES` constant from child classes, so I wouldn't have to repeat this `attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES` for each child class.

Comment: i don't think it's possible also i don't think it's a good idea to do that

Answer (score 3):

Your question is fundamentally flawed. You are inverting the dependency cycle of Class-based inheritance.

Parents *cannot* know anything about their children, by definition of Class-based inheritance.

Moving `attr_accessor` to the `Base` (parent) class would mean it would only have access to values defined *in itself*, not in any of its children!

Comment: I don't think the question is flawed. It's a bit similar to defining a template method in parent that calls another method that should be defined in children. The problem here is that `attr_accessor` is called when the class is being loaded and not when it's used.

Answer (score 0):

You'll define ATTRIBUTES in Base as a Hash associating the class name to the attributes and use the inherited method for Class.

```rb
class Base
  ATTRIBUTES = {
    "ChildNameAge" => [:name, :age],
    "ChildHeightWidth" => [:height, :width]
  }

  def self.inherited(child)
    return unless (attributes = ATTRIBUTES[child.name])
    child.class_eval { attr_accessor *attributes }
  end
end
```

This way, when you'll create your child class it'll be directly defined. But like other said, it's not a good idea (even if it's possible). You cannot document your attributes (using automatic doc like YARD) and when you read the Child implementation, you don't see exactly where the attributes are defined (which can lead to missunderstanding of the classes.)